# bootstrap 4 call javascript function on form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4, form-submit, addeventlistener

So I'm using Bootstrap 4 for my project, and I really like the way their validation works for each input element in a form. I'm using this code to validate my form, this was off their website:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        window.addEventListener(
            "load",
            function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation");
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener(
                        "submit",
                        function (event) {
                            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                event.stopPropagation();
                            }
                            form.classList.add("was-validated");
                        },
                        false
                    );
                });
            },
            false
        );
    })();


</script>
```

The only thing is, in my javascript file, I have another listener that's supposed to get fired when the sign-up button is submitted inside my form. For whatever reason, even once all the input fields are validated, I can't get it to call my submit function. Here's the code inside my javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   initApp();
});


function initApp() {
    document.querySelector("#sign-up").addEventListener("submit", createAccount, false);
}

function createAccount() {
    alert('test');
}
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff like moving this validation code before and after the initialization of my js file, but nothing worked. The goal is to have 2 submit buttons in this form (one is sign up, other is log in) and depending which one is pressed, a different function should be called. If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure what is wrong in your code, I got it working. Maybe you could share more  code so we can check if something is wrong. I can post a runnable script as an answer to show it working.

Answer (score 1):

So if anyone was interested, I fixed my problem by changing the button from submit to a regular button and running validation through my own code. Here's the fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/bv84ncz5/

```
var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation");
// Loop over them and prevent submission
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.classList.add("was-validated");
});

let password = document.querySelector("#password");
let email = document.querySelector("#email");

if (password.checkValidity() === true && email.checkValidity() === true) {
    alert("sup");
}
```

The only thing you need for Bootstrap validation to work is add the class was-validated to each input in the form. Then, you can check if all the forms you want are valid with checkValidity(), and then carrying out what else you want to do

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, I'm not sure what are you doing wrong, must be something. Check this scriptlet working, I changed nothing from you code, I just put it together.

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      initApp();
    });

    function initApp() {
        document.querySelector("#sign-up").addEventListener("submit", createAccount, false);
    }

    (function () {
        "use strict";
        window.addEventListener(
            "load",
            function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("needs-validation");
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener(
                        "submit",
                        function (event) {
                            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                event.stopPropagation();
                            }
                            form.classList.add("was-validated");
                        },
                        false
                    );
                });
            },
            false
        );
    })();

    function createAccount() {
        alert('test');
    }
```

```html
<form id="sign-up">
    <input type="text" class="needs-validation" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I was able to get it to submit if I arrange the code in a certain way, but then the validation won't take place. I'll post more code to see if I can clarify it, but basically the needs-validation class is a container (I have it applied to a form) that allows the (function () { "use strict"; .... to check if the items within needs-validation are up to standard. Basically, I have an email and password input, and if the email input is not formatted correctly that (function()... will apply :invalid psuedo classes to the email input somehow through bootstrap

Comment: So I tried to get a working example on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5s3y4j7L/ but in my javascript I couldn't get the eventlistener to call createAccount on submit. But I noticed that the page will submit once the validation is complete, so it must be something in my code